# What is mean by using square bracket after list comprehension python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
letter_list = [[' '],
               ['a', 'b', 'c'],
               ['d', 'e', 'f'],
               ['g', 'h', 'i'],
               ['j', 'k', 'l'],
               ['m', 'n', 'o'],
               ['p', 'q', 'r', 's'],
               ['t', 'u', 'v'],
               ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z'],
               ['.']

index1_list = [x for x in letter_list if 'g' in x][0]
```

In this example, it is [0]. If I print index1_list it gives lits with a single square bracket. Else it gives 2 square brackets. Why that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `letter_list` is a list of lists. In the list comprehension, you are selecting only the lists which contain the character `g`. Then your `[0]` on the end is taking the first list which contains `g`.